# Why a ViewChild ElementRef has 0 width and height in ngAfterViewInit?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to do some calculations based on element width and height, but for some reason, those are not immediately available on the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook (both are 0).
Though `setTimeout` does seem to do the trick, I don't like it.

What causing this?
Is there a more elegant solution?

```
@ViewChild('main') mainDiv: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {

  this.printMainHeight() // 0

  // with setTimeout width is correctly retrieved ...

  setTimeout(() => this.printMainHeight()) // 430

}

printMainHeight() {

  console.log(this.mainDiv.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height)     

}
```

HTML

```
<div class"main" #main>
  <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
  <app-list></app-list>
</div>
```

Comment: My first thought, think about how fast things happen, at first you have a dom rendered but is it styled yet? What is the height?

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to use `ngAfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook
, not `ngAfterViewInit`.
As Angular docs says about `ngAfterViewChecked()`:

> Respond after Angular checks the component's views and **child views /
>   the view** that a directive is in.
>
> Called after the ngAfterViewInit() and every subsequent
>   ngAfterContentChecked().

Answer (score 0):

That should work unless you have any asynchronous changes in your template in the `<app-toolbar>` or the  `<app-list>`.

**You can check the example here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-afterviewinit-55563149?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

If you see this example, the `#mainDiv` make changes after it was rendered (setTimeout in this example, but it can be anything async, like subscriptions and ajax request) meanwhile the `#syncDiv` load everything synchronous.